# How to refer a funtion as a template variable in Ionic Angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4, angular-template-variable

I have an `Order` object and a Customer Object. The `JSON payload` for the `Order` object is like the following:

```
{
  "order_number" : 1,
  "customer_id": 1
}
```

And this is the `JSON payload` for the `Customer` object

```
{
  "customer_id": 1,
  "customer_name" : 1,
}
```

I have Orders page where I want to display the list of orders. But instead of `order.customer_id` it was to display the `customer_name`

For the I have `getCustomerById` which takes the `customer_id` as a parameter and returns the `customer_name`.

This is my `OrdersPage` class:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OrderService } from '../../services/order.service';
import { Order } from '../../models/order.model';
import { NavController, LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { CustomerService } from 'src/app/services/customer.service';
import { Customer } from 'src/app/models/customer.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-orders',
  templateUrl: './orders.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./orders.page.scss'],
})
export class OrdersPage implements OnInit {
  sender;
  customerName: string;
  destinationName: string;
  // viewOrders = false;
  error;
  orders: Order[];
  subscription: Subscription;
  constructor(private orderService: OrderService,
              private navCtrl: NavController,
              private router: Router,
              private customerService: CustomerService
            ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.orderService.refreshNeeded
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.getAllOrders();
      });
    this.getAllOrders();

  }

  getAllOrders() {

    this.orderService.getAllOrders().subscribe(
      (res: Order[]) => {
        this.orders = res;

      },
      (error) => {
        this.error = error;

      });
  }

  getCustomerById(customerId: number): string {

    this.customerService.getCustomerById(customerId).subscribe(
      (customer: Customer) => {
        this.customerName = customer.name;
      }
    );
    return this.customerName;
  }

}
```

This is `orders.page.html`

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="dark">
    <ion-button slot="end">
      <ion-menu-button> </ion-menu-button>
    </ion-button>
    <ion-title>Orders</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size-md="8" offset-md="2">
      <ion-row class="header-row ion-text-center">
        <ion-col>
          Order number
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          Customer
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row *ngFor="let order of orders; let i = index" class="data-row ion-text-center">
        <ion-col>
          {{order.order_number}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          {{order.customer_id}}
        </ion-col>

        <!-- <ion-col>
        {{getCustomerById(order?.customer_id)}}
      </ion-col> -->
      </ion-row>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

This html works but it returns the `order.customer_id` not the `customer_name`
I have tried to get the name by calling the funtion in the template this way `{{getCustomerById(order?.customer_id)}}` doesn't work and no error in the console as well.

What is the best way to get the `customer_name` field in the order list?

This is my `customer.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Customer } from '../models/customer.model';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomerService {
  url = 'http://api.mydomain.com';

  constructor( ) { }

  getAllCustomers(): Observable<Customer[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Customer[]>(`${this.url}/customers`).pipe();
  }

  getCustomerById(id: number): Observable<Customer> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Customer>(`${this.url}/customer/${id}`).pipe();
  }


}
```

Comment: `this.customerService.getCustomerById` is this async?

Comment: There's a lot you need to correct. First this order object should have a customer_name field from backend because its never a good idea to call server on every iteration of order.

Comment: Also your return statement in getCustomerById is called before `this.customerService.getCustomerById` async function returns you anything because you are not using await.

Comment: @MuhammadUmair, Now I understood, actually it's not async. I have included the CustomerService code in the question now. For now I want to keep my API as is.

Comment: Is there a way to chat on stackoverflow?

Comment: Sure let's do it in chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As mentionned by @Muhammad Umair it is not a good design to make a request to a server for each customer name. Best is to make one request to fetch all wanted curstomer names. The solution below do not take this into consideration.*

Best here is to use a pipe.

*"A pipe takes in data as input and transforms it to a desired output."*
Angular doc

Notice that your request to get your curstomer name is asynchronous (this is why nothing is displayed in your template), here you need to use the async pipe as well :

```
<ion-col> 
    {{ order.customer_id | getCustomerName | async }} 
</ion-col>
```

And here is the pipe (that you should insert into your declarations in your component's module.

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'getCustomerName'
})
export class CustomerNamePipe {

  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) { }

  transform(userIds, args) {
     return this.customerService.getCustomerById(curstomerId);
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you think reaching out to server on every iteration is a good idea?

Comment: @Noelmout, this pipe is returning the customer object not the field right?

Answer (score 0):

Again not a great solution but given the circumstances as you cant change anything in the API. You can modify your file to this.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OrderService } from '../../services/order.service';
import { Order } from '../../models/order.model';
import { NavController, LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { CustomerService } from 'src/app/services/customer.service';
import { Customer } from 'src/app/models/customer.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-orders',
  templateUrl: './orders.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./orders.page.scss'],
})
export class OrdersPage implements OnInit {
  sender;
  customerName: string;
  destinationName: string;
  // viewOrders = false;
  error;
  orders: Order[];
  subscription: Subscription;
  constructor(private orderService: OrderService,
              private navCtrl: NavController,
              private router: Router,
              private customerService: CustomerService
            ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.orderService.refreshNeeded
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.getAllOrders();
        this.getAllCustomers();
      });

    this.getAllOrders();
    this.getAllCustomers();

  }

  getAllOrders() {

    this.orderService.getAllOrders().subscribe(
      (res: Order[]) => {
        this.orders = res;

      },
      (error) => {
        this.error = error;

      });
  }

  getAllCustomers() {

    this.customerService.getAllCustomers().subscribe(
      (customers: Customer[]) => {
        this.customers = customers;
      }
      (error) => {
        this.error = error;

      });
  }

  getCustomerById(customerId: number): string {
    const customer = this.customers.filter(customer => customer.customer_id === customerId );
    return customer.customer_name;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Noelmout mention using pipe I was able to get the `customer_name` with a little bit of change.

This is the `CustomerNamePipe`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomerService } from '../services/customer.service';
import { Customer } from '../models/customer.model';
import { pluck } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Pipe({
  name: 'getCustomerName'
})
export class CustomerNamePipe implements PipeTransform {

  customer: Customer;

  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) { }

  transform(curstomerId, args) {
    return this.customerService.getCustomerById(curstomerId).pipe(pluck('customer_name'));

  }


}
```

This is the order.page.html

```
<ion-col> 
    {{ order.customer_id | getCustomerName | async }} 
</ion-col>
```